# Why can I not fix the error: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (wresult="<t:RequestSecurityTo...")

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried everything and read through all of the related forums in regards to this error, but cannot find a solution. I have published a web application to a server and set it up with AD FS and STS authentication. This error is still showing after following other forums and adding this code to my web.config file:

```
<location path="FederationMetadata">
<system.web>
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
            <pages validateRequest="false" />

      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
```

This application is under an IIS Application pool set at v4.0, and the Application itself has a target framework of 3.5. Are these factors that can prevent me from turning off the validation request that is causing my error here? Am I missing something here? 
I also tried to add the code into the @page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="_Default" validateRequest="false" Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" %>
```

This web app is a simple web forms .aspx page with an embedded .ascx usercontrol if that makes a difference. I am very stuck with this error and would appreciate any help.

Thanks,

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (wresult="<t:RequestSecurityTo..."). 
  Description: ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script. The data might represent an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. If this type of input is appropriate in your application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly allow it. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874. 

 Exception Details: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (wresult="<t:RequestSecurityTo...").

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (wresult="<t:RequestSecurityTo...").]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +12339046
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +203
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +100
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.IsSignInResponse(HttpRequest request) +26
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.CanReadSignInResponse(HttpRequest request, Boolean onPage) +145
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +108
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +92
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

UPDATE FOR COMMENTS: 
I have used this code project as a starting point for this site: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301328/ASP-NETUser-Control-File-Browser . The user controls are basically the same as this. I just added a search function and pictures based on file types. I also changed this into a web application rather than website project.

Comment: Do you edit values on your form with JavaScript? It can be a problem of this issue.

Comment: I use an AjaxControlToolkit reference and have some javascript in the page for displaying a loading .gif, but I don't think that I edit any values with JavaScript.

Comment: It seems as though the error is completely unaffected by adding the validation code to the web.config file. Could I be placing this code in the wrong place and it is not being implemented?

Comment: looks like you have an end location element without an open

Comment: I have edited the code to show the location element. I just didn't copy paste well enough initially

Comment: Somewhere some input is coming as a "sql injection" type statement. Try to sanitize all your post-back to servers and encode all strings.

Comment: Also post your user control html if possible.

Comment: Rex, thank you for your comment. I have edited my question to include the user controls I'm using.

Comment: Could the username variables and ImpersonateUser function be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. It looks like the answer to this issue was right in my face. A coworker was able to find that my code:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
            <pages validateRequest="false" />
```

-was not being implemented as it was inside the location tag. Once I removed the code from inside that  tag and placed it in the  located just below, this error was taken care of. The  tag was created automatically from STS or ADFS as well so I guess that's why I was so confused.

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
                <pages validateRequest="false" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
....
```

I ended up taking out the validateRequest="false" as well to put in the @page directive as I showed above. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. I solved it by adding `requestValidationMode="2.0"` as you mentioned.